# Using \vspace (and other macros) in section headers breaks hyperref PDF-index

Tags: hyperref

the following code compiled with pdflatex produces a PDF file with a PDF index. Sadly, the entry in the index id "5mm Test" instead of just "Test":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{\vspace{5mm} Test}
\end{document}
```

How can I prevent the "5mm" string from occuring in the index? The same happens, for instance, when using \gls in a section title.

Thanks in advance

Yannick

Comment: Use the `\vspace` _before_ `\section` or use `\texorpdfstring{ TeX }{ PDF }`

Comment: Maybe you could redefine the section style for add that space in the preamble for do it automatically instead of each time you write an section head.

Comment: `section[Test]{\vspace{5mm} Test}`?

Comment: Yes, \texorpdfstring does the trick. But the problem stays the same when I use \gls{something}. Then "something" gets printed in the index. And \texorpdfstring does not work here.

Comment: irrespective of hyperref it's so wrong to have formatting commands in the section argument, the section argument should just be the section name, the specification of the format of section heads should be elsewhere, typically the document class